# Finding a row based on 2nd and 3rd TD values

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a table of following structure :-

```
 <tr class="tbs_tr" style="background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery1368711830388="355">
        <TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=0 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368711830388="356"></TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>00-0227101-</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>&nbsp;</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>Medak</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>02/27/2013</TD>
        <TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>02/01/2013</TD>
        </tr>



        <tr class="tbs_tr" style="background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery1368711830388="355">
        <TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=1 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368711830388="358"></TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>01-123456789-</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>2010 Acura CSX 4D Sed</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>Insured Ln, Insured Firstname</TD>
        <TD class=tbs_td>03/05/2013</TD>
        <TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>03/05/2013</TD>
        </tr>


    <tr class="tbs_tr" style="background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery1368711830388="355">
    <TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=2 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368711830388="360"></TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>01-4444-44401</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>01</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>2001 Toyota Tundra 2 Door Pickup 128" WB 8 Foot Bed</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>Naveen</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>02/11/2013</TD>
    <TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>02/10/2013</TD>    </tr>
```

i have two string ex a="01",b="01-4444-44401",Now i want to find each of the rows whose 2nd TD and 3rd  value matches with "a" and "b". Then if this condition meets,then check check box in first TD of each one of that selected rows.

How to do this using jquery?
I am trying to do with "find" and "eq",but don't have idea how to implement this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so that we can help you to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all second cells with text `a` and all third cells with text `b`. Not quite there but almost.

```
$('td:nth-child(2):contains('+a+'), td:nth-child(3):contains('+b+')')
```

[Contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/),
[nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

If you want the resulting object to contains only the rows whose second cell have the text `a` and third cell have the text `b` then you have to do this:

```
var rows = $('tr');
rows.filter(function(i){
    if($(this).find('td:nth-child(2):contains('+a+')') && $(this).find('td:nth-child(3):contains('+b+')')){
        //keep in object
        return true;
    } else {
        //remove from object
        return false;
    }
});
```

[jQuery Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: I have one more condition,like if this condition meets,then check check box in first TD

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - given your above html:

```
var a = "01",
    b = "01-4444-44401",
    rows = $('tr').filter(function(index) { 
    var columns = $(this).children('td');
    return columns.eq(2).text() === a && columns.eq(1).text() === b; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j5C3B/2/